# Determine the minimum total time for everyone to read a book

Tags: algorithm, heap, dynamic-programming

I saw this question somewhere and trying to solve it, is a greedy approach using max heaps possible for this?
i.e Whenever we have a free person, we make them read the choose which takes the most time.

> There are n books.  A group of k people is going to read them all.
> For each book, you know the time it takes to read it.  One person
> reads a book from beginning to end without  switching to another book
> and only one person can read that particular book at a given time.
>
> Determine the minimum total time such that everyone reads every book.
>
> For examples: Input n = 3, k = 3, times = [8, 7, 2]
>
> Output 24
>
> Constraints
>
> 1 < k, n <= 10^5 1 <= ti <= 10^9
>
> Explanation: The first person starts reading the 1st book, the second takes the 2nd book, third takes the 3rd book
> After 2 seconds, the third person waits for another person to finish their book, and this goes on for 24 seconds and in that time, everyone is done with all books

Comment: do you have more use cases?

Comment: n=3, k=2, times=[1,2,3] Then answer will be 6

Comment: Delete this question as its part of a ongoing hiring challenge on Hackerearth.com

Answer (score 2):

No, think of 4 books , 2 persons, times = [8,7,6,1]

the greedy approach(red) would take 23, if you read 1 after 7(green), it takes only 22.
Books named after duration, here's shown in which second what book is read.

[image]

The case persons >= books seems trivial, i'd say its persons * max(times), everyone has to read the longest book.

Comment: I think you have swapped the meaning of n and k?

Comment: Yes, as @trincot pointed out.
Turo In your example, there are 4 person (k=4), and 2 books (n=2) but you have drawn only 2 columns which I guess represents to the 2 persons only. We should have 4 columns there instead.

Comment: Sure, i switched it, thinking the book information would be standing close together. fixed it

Comment: @Batman, swapped or not, the greedy aproach surely fails...